# Si en una novela escrita en español aparece un texto en otro idioma, ¿se deben seguir las reglas de puntuación del otro idioma?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, extranjerismos

La pregunta es un poco genérica, pero os pongo aquí el ejemplo concreto que me apareció el otro día en una novela en la cual he trabajado como corrector ortotipográfico.

> —*A shot?* ¿Un chupito?

El contexto es una fiesta en la cual hay gente tanto del país como turistas extranjeros, y los camareros con bandejas de chupitos tratan de incitar a la bebida primero en inglés y luego en español. Dado que la novela está escrita en español, entendía que, a pesar de ser la primera frase en inglés, debería llevar los signos de interrogación correspondientes al idioma en el que está escrita la novela, de esta forma:

> —¿*A shot*? ¿Un chupito?

Nótese que en el primer caso la interrogación va dentro de la cursiva, para indicar que forma parte del texto en otro idioma, mientras que en el segundo caso saco las interrogaciones de la cursiva y dejo como tal solo el texto.

Al final dejé la frase tal y como me la encontré, como se ve en el primer ejemplo, dado que así me parecía que se reflejaba mejor el hecho de que el camarero estuviera hablando en otro idioma. Pero ¿cuál de las dos formas sería la más correcta? ¿Se deberían usar las reglas de puntuación correspondientes al idioma extranjero y meterlo todo en las cursivas, incluyendo los signos? ¿O se deberían usar las reglas de puntuación del español y poner en cursiva solo el texto?

Comment: En mi opinión, porque la frase es en una otra idioma, la primera sería la más correcto. Me parece como un libro en inglés con un frase del presidente de México en la idioma que lo habló en. En este libro, que actualmente fue parte de mi mente, ellos usaron puntación de español cuando usaron texto en español...

Comment: Yo diría que se usa la puntuación del idioma original, y siempre se escribe en cursiva, como bien has hecho.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con lo de "actualmente fue parte de mi mente"? ¿Es un libro tuyo que todavía no has escrito o algo así?

Comment: El problema es que hay dos tipos de puntuación: la que rodea las frases y la que separa palabras dentro de las frases. Dentro debería quedar igual. Pero por fuera ya no sé. En este caso queda bien, pero no creo que se viera bien en un texto en español, por ejemplo, una cita en alemán con „estas comillas“ o en francés « con este formato ».

Comment: Se podría hacer exactamente la misma pregunta para una novela escrita en inglés (o en cualquier otra lengua) en la que, en un diálogo, un personaje habla en español y hace una pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

[Consultada a la RAE](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/1277587118924148737) a través de Twitter, su respuesta ha sido [la siguiente](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1278029386403454976):

> Si, como en este caso, la secuencia perteneciente a otra lengua constituye un enunciado completo, basta con escribir el signo de cierre y consignar dicho enunciado en cursiva.

Así pues, parece ser que el límite lo constituye la oración. Si lo que se pretende expresar es un enunciado completo (una oración con sentido por sí misma), se pueden dejar los signos de puntuación del idioma original y ponerlo todo en cursiva, de este modo:

> —*A shot?* ¿Un chupito?